# Add tableView to navigationController

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

In viewDidLoad I add a tableview to navigationController like this :

```
[self.view addSubview:navigationController.view];
    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:tableViewRecherchePartenaire];
```

When a row from tableview is selected I want this tableview to disappear and I tried something like this :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 if(indexPath.row==0){
        NSLog(@"RecherchePartenaireTypePartenaireViewController...");


        [self.navigationController.view removeFromSuperview];

        recherchePartenaireTypePartenaireViewController=[[RecherchePartenaireTypePartenaireViewController alloc] init];
        recherchePartenaireTypePartenaireViewController.recherchePartenaireViewController=self.view;

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:recherchePartenaireTypePartenaireViewController animated:YES];
        [recherchePartenaireTypePartenaireViewController release];
    }
}
```

but the tableview disappear but the next view is not appear. How can I use the table view with the navigationController ? Please help...I spent a lot of time with this and I can see the mistake..Thanks in advance..

Comment: Insert

    NSLog(@"%@", [recherchePartenaireTypePartenaireViewController description]);

and tell me what you can see in the console.

Comment: Can you explain why you add a subview directly to the navigation controller's view? Doing so is very uncommon, compared to pushing and popping view controllers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you must not add subview to `UINavigationController`'s view. Put your `UITableView` in a subclass of `UIViewController` and make it the `rootViewController` of your navigationController. You can do it in your main xib file or programmatically :

```
navigationController.rootViewController = myTableViewController;
```

After you can almost keep your function :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if(indexPath.row==0){
        NSLog(@"RecherchePartenaireTypePartenaireViewController...");
        recherchePartenaireTypePartenaireViewController=[[RecherchePartenaireTypePartenaireViewController alloc] init];
                    [self.navigationController pushViewController:recherchePartenaireTypePartenaireViewController animated:YES];
        [recherchePartenaireTypePartenaireViewController release];
    }
}
```

But this function will be in myTableViewController.

In your code, you were removing your navigationController's view from the view hierarchy. So it's normal that nothing came up when you were pushing something, because `UINavigationController` handle push by pushing the next controller's view on it's own view.

Here is a nice Apple's sample that could help you :)
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TheElements/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007419

Comment: this subclass of UIViewController will contain only the tableview? So I must put a tableview on .xib? and the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method will be on .m file?

Answer (score 0):

In your code uitableview is not a navigation type view.So,When you are adding the UITableview to the navigationcontroller's view,superview is uitableview.Ans in didselectrowAtIndexPath you are pushing on the UITableview but not on the NavigationController.So make the UITableview as navigationtype.And then add it to navigationController.And do the same whatever you did.